# Google like search query using Full Text Search in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, search, full-text-search, freetext

I am running a small website wherein I would like to make a functionality like Related Links section.

For that I created fulltext catalog and index.

So far I tried many ways to create search query which behaves like google, but I would say i was not even 10% close to what google is doing.  During my research what i found was only following query was pulling good records.

```
Select col1, col2
from MyTable
Where
FREETEXT(col1,  'User Passed Search Text')
```

Has anyone has good way to create a FullText Search Query which can help in getting better related records for given text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in where condition put * in place of col1 it will search in complete table and gives you result check the link 
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sample-full-text-search-engine